# Unicode CSS Font Awesome Icons Rendering as Boxes in React

Tags: css, reactjs, unicode, font-awesome

I am using the [jPlayer example](https://github.com/jplayer/react-jPlayer-examples/tree/master/jPlayers/AudioPlayer) in a create-react-app. Here is a CodeSandbox showing the issue of font-awesome icon's rendering as boxes.

[image: Edit peaceful-heisenberg-d59nz]

The icons render via css rules specifying content as unicode for `<i>` tags with the `fa` class.

I installed the font-awesome dependency which was in the jPlayer example's `package.json`. Then, I implemented an AudioPlayer component and used the skins provided by jPlayer. The component renders but the icons are all boxes, and I can see the unicode content in the source.

Here's an example of the project architecture. This is the play button in `/src/AudioPlayer/AudioPlayer.jsx`.

`<Play><i className="fa">{/* Icon set in css */}</i></Play>`

Then, the AudioPlayer is imported into `App.jsx`. `App.jsx` imports a stylesheet which has this relevant rule:

```
.fa, .fas, .far {
    font-family: FontAwesome !important;
}
```

`App.jsx` is then rendered by `index.js`. Inside `index.js`, we import the audio player's stylesheets:

```
// Styles the jPlayer to look nice
import 'react-jplayer/dist/css/skins/sleek.min.css';
// Styles Play/Pause/Mute etc when icons (<i />) are used for them
import 'react-jplayer/dist/css/controls/iconControls.min.css';
```

The rule for the play button in `iconControls.css` looks like this:

```
.jp-jplayer .jp-icon-controls .jp-play i:before {
  content: "\F04B";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

then within `index.html`'s `head` I include the font-awesome CDN as a final attempt at fixing the boxes being rendered instead of font-awesome icons.

Comment: Remember to look at your post after hitting the submit button, just in case you got the markdown formatting wrong. Which you did. Easy enough to fix, but others shouldn't have to do that for you.

Comment: Sorry but I do not see an error in formatting

Comment: You have code blocks that correctly use block formatting, and then you have code blocks that use inline formatting instead, so instead of being a nice full width block of "code over multiple lines", it's just paragraph text.

Comment: Oh, I see, the imports for the jPlayer style sheets are line-by-line.

Comment: You have multi-line CSS that should be a block, too. Remember that this is not github, SO has [its own markdown rules](/editing-help). And on a more ["asking a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) note: please do not ask people to clone your project, you're responsible for making sure that your post contains all the details necessary to sensibly comment on the problem you're having, so you may need to form a [mcve] instead. Especially since your code _won't_ have this problem anymore soon, that link will soon be of no use to future visitors of the site, looking for answers the same way you have.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Good idea with the example. I created one using CodeSandbox.

Comment: Please don't: the whole idea of "your post should contain all the details" is that we don't want links to external sites unless they're to run the code that's _already in your post_: external links die, and if a link dying can make your question meaningless, that's not a good question. SO exists for the benefit of everyone with the same problem as you, so please help make sure those future visitors can see the full question. Not just "go to this link to see the _actual_ code" and then a dead link. Reduce your code to the bare minimum for the purposes of this question, then ask about that.

Comment: The CodeSandbox is the minimal reproducible example and only contains the assets mentioned in the post.

Comment: Yes, and will expire in the future. If you want to provide people with an off-site way to view/run the code, please do that as a way for people to run the mcve code you've shown in your post. Not instead of. We _explicitly_ ask you to do this over on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, under "Help others reproduce the problem", second point, with that request **in bold** so you don't miss it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the styles.css there is FontAwesome !important as shown below which is overriding the FontAwesome 5 Free font. You could remove this style to see the fonts coming up.

```css
fa, .fas, .far {
    font-family: FontAwesome !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried this in the CodeSandbox and the icons are still rendered as boxes.

Comment: I saw the sand box url , I think font awesome style link is missing from index.html. You could add it back and refresh the page
https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-rain-xk7ce

Answer (score 0):

Font characters show as open squares when:

1. The Unicode character specified doesn't exist in the font file.
2. The requested font file can't be found and there's no fallback specified.

Since its's Font Awesome, there's no fallback font AND the requested character doesn't exist in most fonts. So you get a double problem.

This almost always happens when the browser can't find the font file due to path issues. I'd look through your CSS to find where `@font-face` is requested and fix the path to match your project. I would guess this is in the player CSS file AND that it expect's a local file not from the CDN.

Also, be aware that Webpack sometimes moves files and updates paths found in CSS so you may need to move those to a "static" directory and change paths as needed.

Finally, you should check the name of the font to make sure it matches what you have available in your system. According to Font Awesome's Docs, it should be `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";` your's seems to have an extra back slash.

Comment: I created a CodeSandbox which shows the css styling is very minimal. font-face is never requested from any of the stylesheets.